# System of Equations İnvolving Floor Function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, ceiling-and-floor-functions

**The Question**

> Solve for $(x,y,z)$
>
> $$\left\{\begin{matrix} x+\left \lfloor y \right \rfloor + \left \{ z
> > \right \}=1,1\\  z+\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor + \left \{ y \right
> > \}=2,2\\  y+\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor + \left \{ z \right \}=3,3
>  \end{matrix}\right.$$

**My Understanding**

From the definition of floor function we know that $n = \left \lfloor n \right \rfloor + \left \{n  \right \}$ and if you play with equation a bit $(1,1+,2,2=3,3)$ and do some cancelling it's easy to see that

$$x+z=0 \Rightarrow x = -z.$$

After that you set $z=-x$ and rewrite the equation. You'll see from $[2(1,1)=2,2]$ and a bit cancelling $\left \{ y \right \} - \left \{ x \right \}=2,2$. Also an important note that $\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor \neq \left \lfloor -x \right \rfloor , \left \{ x \right \} \neq \left \{ -x \right \}$ example: $\left \lfloor 5,35 \right \rfloor = 5$ but $\left \lfloor -5,35 \right \rfloor = -6$. I got this so far and need help.

Comment: What do you mean by writing two numbers separated by commas? I understand $x+\lfloor y\rfloor+\{z\}=1$ but I don't understand $x+\lfloor y\rfloor+\{z\}=1,1$.

Comment: oh it is a float value like 0,5 or 1,4

Comment: I have seen this question before with same figures where last equation was $y+\lfloor z\rfloor+\{x\}=3.3$ and of course all commas were decimals. You could format to not cause confusion.

Comment: Well, @BilalErgüç then please change all commas with decimals. I got really confused.

Comment: I got this problem from an online proof writing course, it is one of the questions in my homework.

Comment: sry ı am new to stack this is my second question

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3h1930276p13254747

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1132158p5265698

Comment: these are similar problems but in this question, variables are not symmetrical

Comment: In some countries, decimals are denoted by commas.  So asking them to be changed is unreasonable.  But including a note explaining it may be desirable.  Similarly, we sometimes see sen for sin and tg for tan.  No need to change them, but do explain what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

These equations have no solution since the LH sides of equations (2) and (3) have the same fractional part, formed from the sum of the fractional parts of $y$ and $z$, and yet differ by $1.1$.

N.B. Looking at the comment of @cosmo5 I suspect that the last equation should be as in that comment. Then there is the solution $x=0.1,y=1.2,z=2$.

Comment: ı don't get what you mean could you open it up a bit

Comment: Yes, I've added to the answer.